# RelativeLayout Problems with differences in height

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android studio it should be like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNYuv.png
but when I run it on my phone it shows up like this with the 2 edittexts that have moved up a bitin relation compared to the backround screen.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH0cJ.png

I am relatively new to android and would like help on how to make sure that it will be in ratio and work on different phone sizes. It is the 2 editTexts that have changed position. Thanks in advance

XML CODE FOR REFERENCE

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/mainscreen" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/predict_b"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text="Enter Name"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:linksClickable="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="Age"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:linksClickable="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText" />
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button" />
```

Comment: where to put check box ?? age and name is edit text after that which component u want to add give proper image

Comment: @jitendraparmar forget about the checkbox. I am talking about the 2 editTexts that have changed their position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not using LinearLayout instead ?
use LinearLayout with orientation vertical
or you can also use it with weightSum tag

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to the activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Try modifying your layout as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/urLogiOrTitle" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:text="Enter Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:text="Age" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="predict" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The editTexts still moves in relation to the backround which i put in the RelativeLayout backround

Comment: I did and it did the same as last time

Comment: So the editTexts stay on in the bar in the same position in how it is in android studio when the program is run on my phone.

Comment: change position after keyboard open ??

Comment: When i run it on my phone the edittexts move like 20 dp up compared to how it looks in android studio and then on my phone when text selection opens the edits texts move down like 20 dp. It shows in the pictures

Comment: It now moves with the keyboard which is not what i wanted. If you go and see the pictures you can see the difference in the position of edittexts

Comment: i seen your pictures u set edittext background as image  ??

Comment: No the relativelayout backround is now the blue background screen

Comment: add android:layout_centerVertical="true" to edittext

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your EditTExt:

```
android:textAlignment="center"
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: Both editTexts still moved up around 20dp when ran on phone